# Static field in the java library

Tags: java, http, static

I'm using java SDK library of one payment system.

In that library you have to set up API key which they provided to you before in the static field:

```
public static volatile String apiKey;
```

Each HTTP request which was made by this library involve this apiKey in headers.

My task - make aggregator of users of that payment system. Each user has his own API Key.

When the number of users was 2, I've just made bad thing:

```
public synchronized void pay() {
     Library.apiKey = securityService.currentUser().key();
     Library.pay(...)
     ...
}
```

It works but everyone understands that it is a bad bad bad practice. Now I have to support more than 100 users. My decision will be in 100 times slower not to mention another problems.

I want to continue to use this library. But in multithread way. Of course, if I make a request by myself I will do smth like this:

```
public void pay() {
     HttpHeader headers;
     headers.put("api_key", securityService.user().key());
     httpClient.post(headers...)
}
```

I understand that this library just doesn't fit to my task. But I need that library, it does a lot of work inside themself.

If there is no possibility I have to fork it and change to fit my demands.

I attach the link to source code of the library.
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/stripe

Comment: Did you read the documentation (README) of the github repo you have provided? It clearly mentions an alternative way to deal with multiple key scenarios.
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java#per-request-configuration

Comment: @Udith Gunaratna thanks, I missed it, I read docs on site but not in the Github repository.

Answer (score 0):

All of the request methods accept an optional `RequestOptions` object. In the `RequestOptions` you can add a secret API key to each method.

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder()
    .setApiKey("sk_test_...")
    .build();
```